# How to get a tree-like output of mysql select queries on command line?

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line, configuration

I know that there is a way to get a different view of the output generated by a mysql select query from command line. Yet I forgot how to activate it and I am quite oblivious how to search for the feature.

Standard behavior is an printed horizontal table with lots of ASCII-symbols and each field is printed next to another. The alternative approach is more, for lack of a better words, yml- or tree-like. It lists the data vertically and I found it to be more human-readable, especially on small terminals.

Could anybody enlighten me how to activate that output mode again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to the `\G` option, [the vertical mode](http://blog.nachtarbeiter.net/2010/01/19/display-mysql-query-output-on-the-command-line/) or according to `mysql help` the ego mode.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1\G
```

To make it standard behaviour add the following to your `.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
vertical
```

Comment: Exactly. Silly me was only trying `\g` :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `mk-visual-explain` ?

[mk-visual-explain](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mk-visual-explain)

Comment: No, I wasn't looking for this but this seems nice, too. Could you add a few more relevant information from the link into your answer? An answer should stand on its own and not be merely a link.